# Render/Display Articulate content with Iframe

Tags: articulate-storyline, articulate

I publish Articulate content with LMS Option and choose Tin Can API option in Output Options section.

Now when i Render/Display it with Iframe and when i click in Any link it throw following error. Please help me to figure it out.

> app.min.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of
>   undefined at t.checkFlow (app.min.js:40) at
>   Object.r.invokeGuardedCallback (app.min.js:8) at o (app.min.js:5) at
>   Object.a [as executeDispatchesInOrder] (app.min.js:5) at d
>   (app.min.js:5) at m (app.min.js:5) at Array.forEach () at n
>   (app.min.js:10) at Object.processEventQueue (app.min.js:5) at n
>   (app.min.js:8)

[image]

Comment: Get @SamitKhulve I am gettingt he same issue. Were you able to resolve it? Mine is with Articulate 3, but I believe it has something to do with the launch URL. What is your launch url?

Comment: Hi Trip, Actually it is because i choose *Tin Can API option* while exporting, and Learning Locker is required for  *Tin Can API*